# neural network data for training and testing

Tags: neural-network

I have a question regarding Training and testing data for my ANN .

Should the testing data going trough a feature extraction process before it can be classified?
I am new to this field. Is what I am doing right? 
I separate the dataset to 80% train and 20 % test. Both sets , I extract the features. for train data I put it into training network but not for the test data. Then go to classification. Is this correct? because my SV said the test data should not go through the feature extraction process. I am wondering how the ANN can recognize the input if not specific feature is being extract. Apologize my bad English.

If anyone have link or journal that I can refer please provide it..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Both the training and the test data needs to be in the same format - thus your training data and test data should go through the same pre-processing steps else your network will not learn correctly.

Comment: Thanks Soaring_Lion...do you have any journal or paper so that I can read?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right (as far as I understand your question).

Example: If you were to show me 10 *images* of faces (training data) on paper and then present me 2 people (training data) by their *name only* (different feature representation) - I wouldn't be able to classify what I didn't learn. You can't train the network with images and then test it with audio or any representation other than the one you used for training. I can't link any papers for that as it's just common sense.

You *can* modify the training set, e.g. by adding noise. But whatever you do, the representation format has to be the same.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the explanation Malch. I hope I can convince my SV. Thanks a gain.

Comment: It's probably a misunderstanding. Just do what makes sense for you. If it works, it works.